# MySQL get Related and Unrelated Records from Table in One Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a user and pages table, and these two have many to many relationship between them with the bridge table user privileges. What I want to get all the pages name and only those are marked that is assigned to that user.

want some think like this

```
+---------+----------------------------------+
| user_id | page_name              | Assigned|
+---------+----------------------------------+
|       1 | Add Project            |   0     |
|       1 | Department             |   0     |
|       1 | Category               |   1     |
|       1 | Item                   |   0     |
|       1 | Units                  |   1     |
|       1 | Stock In               |   0     |
|       1 | Stock Card Report      |   1     |
+---------+------------------------+---------|
```

for now my query is this;

```
Select up.user_id, p.page_name FROM user_privileges up, pages p where p.page_id = up.page_id and up.user_id = 1;
```

and it returns this;

```
+---------+------------------------+
| user_id | page_name              |
+---------+------------------------+
|       1 | Add Project            |
|       1 | Department             |
|       1 | Category               |
|       1 | Item                   |
|       1 | Units                  |
|       1 | Stock In               |
|       1 | Stock Card Report      |
+---------+------------------------+
```

The Scheme is this;
table - user

```
+---------+-----------+
| user_id | user_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       4 |  saif     |
|       1 | admin     |
|       5 | taqi      |
|       2 | rashid    |
+---------+-----------+
```

table - pages

```
+---------+---------------+
| page_id | page_name     |
+---------+---------------+
|       2 | Page 1        |
|       3 | Page 2        |
|       5 | Page 3        |
|       6 | Page 4        |
|       7 | Page 5        |
|       8 | Page 6        |
|       9 | Page 7        |
|      10 | Page 8        |
|      11 | Page 9        |
|      13 | Page 10       |
|      14 | Page 11       |
|      15 | Page 12       |
|      16 | Page 13       |
|      18 | Page 14       |
|      19 | Page 15       |
|      20 | Page 16       | 
+---------+---------------+
```

and table user_privalges for user_id = 1 only.

```
+--------------------+---------+---------+
| user_privileges_id | user_id | page_id |
+--------------------+---------+---------+
|                  1 |       1 |       2 |
|                  2 |       1 |       3 |
|                  3 |       1 |       5 |
|                  4 |       1 |       6 |
|                  5 |       1 |       7 |
|                  6 |       1 |       8 |
|                  7 |       1 |       9 |
|                  8 |       1 |      10 |
|                  9 |       1 |      11 |
|                 10 |       1 |      13 |
|                 11 |       1 |      14 |
|                 12 |       1 |      15 |
|                 13 |       1 |      16 |
|                 14 |       1 |      18 |
|                 15 |       1 |      19 |
|                 16 |       1 |      20 |
+--------------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Please provide sample data best is with [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select up.user_id, p.page_name FROM user_privileges up, pages p where p.page_id = up.page_id and up.user_id = 1 AND up.Assigned=1;
```

"What I want to get all the pages name and only those are marked that is assigned to that user." So with your edit you should try something like that with case statement

```
SELECT up.user_id, p.page_name,
 CASE 
  WHEN up.page_id=p.page_id THEN '1'   
  ELSE '0'
 END AS Assigned
FROM pages p left join user_privileges up 
ON p.page_id = up.page_id
WHERE up.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: there no such fields `Assigned`.

Comment: can you provide us the creation scripts be cause from your exemple we can understand 2 things: 1/ You already have a filed "Assigned" (picture 1) 2/If a user is already only linked to pages he has privileges on, you don't need to have a "Assigned" column full of ones (picture 2)

Comment: Check the question now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for the `user_id = 1` you may do something as

```
select
1 as user_id,
p.page_name,
case when up.page_id is not null then 1 else 0 end as `Assigned`
from pages p
left join user_privalges up on up.page_id = p.page_id and up.user_id = 1 
order by p.page_id
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06f65/5